# Import Template:Note on a new MediaWiki wiki

Tags: templates, mediawiki

I have set up a MediaWiki wiki and now I want to include a Template called "note" ([Templatelink](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Template:Note)).
I have used the Special:Export page and imported it. But there is clearly something wrong:[image]
The tags seem to work, but the pictures not. Also the translation extension, but I guess thats not the point.
How do I get the files for this template? Why aren't the exported too. 
Am I missing important dependencies? And if yes: How do I know which ones a template needs?

Answer (score 0):

MediaWiki exports into a xml format file, and whilst it is possible to for example base64 encode an image, it is not a nice way to export an image (especially true for big images). There are also potentiel issues with licenses for images from other wikis, as MediaWiki is a software that isn't just used on Wikipedia and its sister-projects.

You can get the files by going to the File: page of said file on the source wiki you exported this template from (you can get the file name from the redlink for example).

On a sidenote: Wikimedia is the foundation that runs wikipedia, you probably just set up a wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solve it in this way:

Copy the complete contents of this file:

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Gadget-site.css

In this:

https://your-wiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Common.css

Change "your-wiki.org" With your url.

It's everything, with this it should work.